# How to select a database with variable name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have databases like

```
S01_2017925
S01_2017926
S01_20170926_105439
S01_20170926_122707
```

where the `S01` is a name of the database, `20170925` is date when it was created and `122707` a time if more then once per day.

What I want to do is to select a name of the last (current) database.

I've tried:

```
select MAX(db_name()) 
from sys.databases 
where db_name() like 'S01_%'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `DB_NAME()` is a function that returns the name of the current database if you don't pass an argument. You want the `name` column.

Comment: What do you mean by "name column"?

Comment: select * 
from sys.databases 
where name like 'S01_%'
order by create_date desc

Comment: Why would you create database on daily basis ? database design has to be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `name` column for filter instead of `db_name()`

```
select MAX(name) 
from sys.databases 
where name like 'S01_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could get the last created/restored database like this

```
select top 1 name 
from   sys.databases 
where  name like 'S01_%'
order by create_date desc
```

But I am not sure if this will get you your current database.
For this to work your current database has to be the last database created (or restored)